# Is return value important in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am writing the Firebase Could Functions with TypeScript and the following is a simple method to update a document.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

export const handleTestData = functions.firestore.document('test/{docID}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const data = snap.data();
    if (data) {
        try {
                await admin.firestore().doc('test1/' + context.params.docID + '/').update({duplicate : true});
            } catch (error) {}
    }
});
```

In this method, the promise is handled by `async` `await` and there is no `return` statement and it's working fine. Most of the examples/tutorials I have seen always have a `return` statement in each method.
Is there any impact/difference I don't return anything in Firebase Cloud Functions? If I should return something, can I return `null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is return value important in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Yes, it is really **key**, in a Cloud Function which performs asynchronous processing (also known as "background functions") to return a JavaScript promise when all the asynchronous processing is complete, as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions?authuser=0).

Doing so is important for two main reasons (excerpts from the doc):

1. You make sure that the Cloud Functions instance running your Cloud Function does not shut down before your function successfully reaches its terminating condition or state.
2. You can avoid excessive charges from Cloud Functions that run for too long or loop infinitely.

---

**Why is your Cloud Function running correctly even if you don't return a Promise?**

Normally your Cloud Function should be terminated before the asynchronous operations are completed, because you don't return a Promise and therefore indicate to the Cloud Functions platform that it can terminate the Cloud Functions instance running the Cloud Function.

But sometimes, the Cloud Functions platform does not terminate the Function immediately and the asynchronous operations can be completed. This is not at all guaranteed and totally out of your control.

Experience has shown that for short asynchronous operations this last case happens quite often and the developer thinks that everything is ok. But, all of sudden, one day, the Cloud Function does not work... and sometimes it does work: The developer is facing an "erratic" behaviour without any clear logic, making things very difficult to debug. You will find a lot of questions in Stack Overflow that illustrate this situation.

---

So concretely, in your case you can adapt your code like:

```
export const handleTestData = functions.firestore.document('test/{docID}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const data = snap.data();
    if (data) {
        try {   
                // See the return below: we return the Promise returned by update()
                return admin.firestore().doc('test1/' + context.params.docID + '/').update({duplicate : true});
         } catch (error) {
               return null;  // <- See the return
        }
    } else {
       return null;  // <- See the return
    }
});
```

or like

```
export const handleTestData = functions.firestore.document('test/{docID}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const data = snap.data();
    if (data) {
        try {
                await admin.firestore().doc('test1/' + context.params.docID + '/').update({duplicate : true});
                return null;  // <- See the return
         } catch (error) {
               return null;  // <- See the return
        }
    } else {
       return null;  // <- See the return
    }
});
```

Returning `null` (or `true`, or `1`...) is valid since an `async` function always returns a Promise.

Comment: Hi @Renaud, thanks a lot for the explanation. One question. I have some bigger functions with lots of branches to end the function. Can I just return null once at the end of the function instead of returning it in all branches? Like for example, you are returning null in the 3 places in the example code. Will that be the same as returning null at the end of the function. Because if the `if(data)` fails, that should also return a promise.

Comment: Yes, since you are using `async/await` you can write your code similarly to synchronous code. If you would use `then()` instead of `async/await` you would have to take care not calling `return` before the asynchronous work is completed.